# DNS server address after migrate the ADDS & DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

currently, I'm facing an Windows AD environment that needs to migrate the AD&DNS server to another machine.

Assume that the original AD&DNS server named VM-A(IP:10.1.1.1) is the only one domain controller and will migrate to another WinServer named VM-B(IP:10.1.1.2).

And then, the servers/clients/devices under this domain are using 10.1.1.1 as their DNS server address(only this one address) now.

So the questions are, after the migration of ADDS & DNS role to VM-B and the deletion of VM-A, will the servers/clients/devices face DNS problems immediately?

Should I change the DNS server address for these servers/clients/devices beforehand or after the ADDS/DNS migration? Which would be the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the questions are, after the migration of ADDS & DNS role to VM-B
>   and the deletion of VM-A, will the servers/clients/devices face DNS
>   problems immediately?

Yes, they will.

> Should I change the DNS server address for these
>   servers/clients/devices beforehand or after the ADDS/DNS migration?
>   Which would be the best practice?

Change it beforehand.